# importing android .zip file in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded CustomView.zip file from google's android developer's site, but i have not been able to import it into my eclipse ide, it showing no projects found when selecting this archive file.

Comment: Look at the import settings for eclipse? You also have to extract the files from the zip

Comment: I encountered the same problem. I did thought that it's missing the AndroidManifest.xml file. I tried to fix it and place it here https://github.com/inspire365/android-customviews-fixed . You can download it an try.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the zip file and in eclipse under select Android Application Project from existing code and import the project. That is it.

Comment: I have the same problem - even after extracting. Eclipse does not recognise the directory as a project.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the Zip file and then import it from the eclipse .